# How to select a row by value-set it as the header row-drop all the rows up to that value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as this:

```
0  1   2   3   4
1  a   b   c   d
2  a   b   c   d
3  a   b   c   d
4 gab fob upo tem
```

What I would like to do is make row 4 the header and drop the rows above it.
The key is that the source data is being read from an excel and the format of the report could change, so it may all of the sudden, start looking like this:

```
0  1   2   3   4
1  a   b   c   d
2 gab fob upo tem
3  a   b   c   d
4  a   b   c   d
```

I know I could do this:

```
df.read_excel('filename', skiprows=4, header=1)
```

However, I need to keep all of this independent of the order of the dataframe because that could change.

So, I need to select a row with a specific value, make that row the header and then delete/drop all the rows that lead up to that row that I selected if they are left in the dataframe (probably dependent on how the code is written).

Everything that I've looked up seems to assume the data columns/rows won't change from load to load.

I hope I worded this well enough to make sense.....

Comment: Is there a programmatic way of determining which row should be the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know what the headers are, you can search for them:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=None)
headers = [2, 'gab','fob','upo','tem']

starts = (df==headers).all(1).idxmax()

df.columns=df.loc[starts]
df = df.iloc[starts+1:]
```

Output:

```
1  2 gab fob upo tem
2  3   a   b   c   d
3  4   a   b   c   d
```

Comment: I like this but the file has about 20 columns so is there a way to shorten it so I wouldn't have to code all the header values (also, some of the header values are 3-4 words long, ugh)?

Comment: Depending on what criteria you want a row to be header. You can just check for one column, e.g. to check on second column `starts = (df.loc[:,1] == 'gab').idxmax()`

Comment: Could I just search for the row by one value? For instance: find the row with this value in it, then make that whole row the header. I am a newbie so thank you for baring with me.

Comment: Yes, `starts = (df == 'gab').any(1).idxmax()`.

Comment: Great, I'll try this out tomorrow. Thank you for your help!